# Declaration syntax error in function

Tags: c++, syntax, declaration, turbo-c++

Please help me fix this problem I typed the code at school too even there it showed declaration syntax error. -.- Cannot figure this out! . Its so frustrating when you have just begun with learning coding.

void issue error: declaration syntax error
void display error: illegal use of pointer

Apologies if any folly in me found.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


class book
{
char bookname[20];
char isbn[20];
char author[20];
char category[20];
float price;
int noc;

public:

void accept()
{

cout<<"Enter book name :- \n";
gets(bookname);
cout<<"Enter isbn no of the book:- \n";
gets(isbn);
cout<<"Enter authour name:- \n";
gets(author);
cout<<"Enter category of book:- \n";
gets(category);
cout<<"Enter price of the book :- \n";
cin>>price;
cout<<"Enter no of copies of book available in the library :- \n";
cin>>noc;
}

void display()
{
puts(bookname)<<endl;
puts(isbn)<<endl;
puts(author)<<endl;
puts(category)<<endl;
cout<<price<<endl;
cout<<noc<<endl;
}

}b[5];

int main()
{
for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
{
b[i].accept();
}

void issue()
{
int flag=0;
char booksearch[20];
cout<<"Enter name of book member wants to issue :- \n"
gets(booksearch);
  for(i=0;i<5;++i)
  {
      flag=strcmp(booksearch,b[i].bookname)
  }

}

 if(flag==1)
 {
   b[i].display();
   b[i].issue();
 }
 getch();
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: can you be more specific.. and post some more of your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In particular you should include the complete copy-pasted error in your question.

Comment: Are you using a plain text editor or a word processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous errors with your code:

1. Missing semicolon after the `strcmp` call:
2. `strcmp` returns 0 when there is a match, not 1, and you potentially overwrite flag on the next iteration of the loop,
3. Your definition of `issue` is in the middle of `main`,
4. You are mixing c-style gets and c++-style operator >>,
5. You are mixing - badly - c-style puts and operator <<

Here is the non-working version of your code:
http://ideone.com/sGdXcm

Here is a fixed, working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

class book
{
    std::string bookname;
    std::string isbn;
    std::string author;
    std::string category;
    float price;
    int noc;

public:
    const std::string& getBookname() const { return bookname; }
    const std::string& getISBN() const { return isbn; }
    const std::string& getAuthor() const { return author; }
    const std::string& getCategory() const { return category; }
    float getPrice() const { return price; }
    float getNoC() const { return noc; }

    void accept()
    {
        cout<<"Enter book name :- \n";
        std::getline(std::cin, bookname);
        cout<<"Enter isbn no of the book:- \n";
        std::getline(std::cin, isbn);
        cout<<"Enter authour name:- \n";
        std::getline(std::cin, author);
        cout<<"Enter category of book:- \n";
        std::getline(std::cin, category);
        cout<<"Enter price of the book :- \n";
        std::cin>>price;
        cout<<"Enter no of copies of book available in the library :- \n";
        std::cin>>noc;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout<<bookname<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<isbn<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<author<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<category<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<price<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<noc<<std::endl;
    }

    void issue()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::array<book, 5> b;
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();++i)
    {
        b[i].accept();
    }

    std::string booksearch;
    std::cout<<"Enter name of book member wants to issue :- \n";
    std::getline(cin, booksearch);
    std::cout<<"Searching for: " << booksearch << "\n";
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();++i)
    {
        if (b[i].getBookname() == booksearch)
        {
            b[i].display();
            b[i].issue();
            break;
        }
    }

    std::string dummy;
    std::cout << "Hit return:";
    std::getline(std::cin, dummy);

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/p3Ygw3

Note: I didn't add any error checking to this code, if the user makes a typo while entering books things will go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a semicolon after your `flag=strcmp (searchbook, b [I]. bookname)` line.
2. Declare `flag`, `searchbook`, `b` if not already declared.
3. Do `#include <string.h>` before your function